# Google OR Tools - Setting time window dimensions fails with low level error

Tags: c#, or-tools

So am trying to use the VRPTW example at  https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw as a basis for some of my own code.

In my case I want to schedule over multiple days with multiple vehicles (each starting/returning at the driver's home).
In the example, it is assumed that there is one depot from which all vehicles start on the one day. The first column of the time matrix is the depot number and I believe the 0 index in that code is because all vehicles leave/return from the depot.

```
// Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
for (int i = 0; i < data.VehicleNumber; ++i)
{
    long index = routing.Start(i);
    timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(data.TimeWindows[0, 0], data.TimeWindows[0, 1]);
}
```

So in my case lets say I have three days for delivers by the two vehicles, in my time matrix I have columns for:

- Day1 - Vehicle 1  (starts/returns from Position A)
- Day1 - Vehicle 2  (starts/returns from Position B)
- Day2 - Vehicle 1  (starts/returns from Position A)
- Day2 - Vehicle 2  (starts/returns from Position B)
- Day3 - Vehicle 1  (starts/returns from Position A)
- Day3 - Vehicle 2  (starts/returns from Position B)

I then have an array of vehicle start and end nodes, to point to these entries. All this is working fine and I am happy with the results or-tools is providing.

Where I have a problem is that I now want to set time windows for each of the vehicles. So should look like this:

- Day 1 - Vehicle 1 Time Window 0-1440
- Day 1 - Vehicle 2 Time Window 0-1440
- Day 2 - Vehicle 1 Time Window 1440-2880
- Day 2 - Vehicle 2 Time Window 1440-2880
- Day 3 - Vehicle 1 Time Window 2880-4320
- Day 3 - Vehicle 2 Time Window 2880-4320

So I have changed the example code above to the code below. I thought the code looked ok but it falls over with "Could not get your data. fail" (which seems like a pretty low level error) at the indicated line.

```
        var useIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.DayCount; i++)
        {
            var fromTime = i * 1440;
            var toTime = (i + 1) * 1440;
            for (int j = 0; j < data.VehicleCount; ++j)
            {
                long index = routing.Start(useIndex);
                timeDimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(fromTime, toTime);   <---- FAILS HERE

                useIndex++;
            }
        }
```

It goes through the first day fine, setting the values to 0-1440. It is when it does the second loop and tries to set the values to 1440-2880 that it fails. If I set all values to 0-1440 on every loop it is fine. So its only when I attempt to change the value that there is a problem. Any thoughts on why?

**Edit 1**
The stacktrace of the error message shows the error occurs here :

at Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver.IntExpr.SetRange(Int64 l, Int64 u)

I am using Google.OrTools 9.0.9048

**Edit 2**
It looks like the *from* value has to start with 0 (0-1440 is fine). If I try to assign all ranges to 1440-2880, it fails immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: `SetRange()` checks if the new range requested is in the domain, and fail otherwise.

Question: What is the vehicle capacity (aka horizon) for the time dimension ?
It must be at least 4320 !

i.e. when you used something like this

```py
routing.AddDimension(
  transit_evaluator_index,
  X, # max Slack time aka waiting time here
  Y, # <=== HERE vehicle capacity
  False, # Force start cumul to zero (not wanted for time dimension) 
  "Time") # name of the dimension and used as uid
```

I mean, all range values must be less or equal to Y.

Comment: I had Y set to 100,000. I am trying to set the range to 1440-2880 so should be ok. However, you have false for the 4th property where I had true. If I make it false, I no longer get the error.

Comment: Make it true, means you'll force the time_dimension.CumulVar(any_start_node) to be zero, BUT if at the same time you have a range for start node to be [1440-2880] or [2880-4320] you just make your problem infeasible since 0 is not in the range...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SetRange. Use the Solver.Add(solver.MakeBetweenCt()).
The SetRange API is meant to be used inside the search.

Comment: I had to go back to the Resource Constraint example at https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrptw_resources to work out what you were getting at here and how it might work. I think I get where you are coming from and I can see its use in some other things that I still have to do but extrapolating from the Time Window Constraints example and setting true to false as per my comment on Mizux's answer, I think I am currently ok with NOT using MakeBetweenCt, unless there is some compelling reason I have missed.